# Eclipse compiler error after upgrading library version

Tags: java, json, jackson

I had Jackson 1.8.2, and everything worked except the nested geo_position property.

After browsing through some SO questions, I've upgraded to Jackson 1.9.x, now Jackson manages to recognize the Position nested class, but complains about the latitude primitive float property.

Also, eclipse gives out a weird error when I try to compile the project after I upgraded to the new Jackson version:
Tried down-grading back to 1.8.2, but no luck.
What's weird about this is that there are no actual errors, and the validation of the project goes through just fine.

[image]

Stack trace:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "latitude" (Class task.Position), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@14de991; line: 1, column: 64] (through reference chain: task.ResultSet["results"]->task.Location["geo_position"]->task.Position["latitude"])null

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:194)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:30)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
at task.JSONParser.fromNative(JSONParser.java:24)
at task.RESTClient.main(RESTClient.java:85)
```

Code:
https://github.com/BeOleg/JavaRestClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in the .classpath file which is located in the projects root, eclipse left the old version of the core-jackson jar, alongside with the new one, this was causing all the errors!

I am really going to use intelli-j next time I have to use Java...

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/fluent-hc-4.3.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpclient-4.3.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpclient-cache-4.3.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpcore-4.3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpmime-4.3.2.jar"/>
    //Just erased bellow line:
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

All credits to @Yuri Prezument :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate `task.Position` with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to ignore the properties you don't want.

`Unrecognized field "latitude" (Class task.Position), not marked as ignorable`

Comment: This is trivial my friend, believe me, I've read the stack trace before posting it.
Still, thanks.